# About MIT 6.00 course lec06--Newton's method

Tags: python, math, newtons-method

I have tried to code in my own way, but found I got the wrong answer.

I have read [this page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) And try to start the process:

[image]

f(x)=x^2-e

The math:

[image]

So there is my code:

```
def sqrtRootNR(num, count, epsl):
    """
    for test
    """
    num = float(num)
    guess = num / 2.0
    diff = guess ** 2.0 - num
    _cnt = 0
    while abs(diff) > epsl and _cnt < count:
        guess = guess - (guess ** 2.0 + epsl) / (guess * 2.0)
        diff = guess ** 2.0 - num
        _cnt = _cnt +1
    print guess, _cnt

sqrtRootNR(2, 100, 0.0001)
```

However, I got the wrong answer.

The output of this function is:

> D:\poc>python sq.py
>
> 0.0595177826557 100

Comment: What answer did you get?  What answer did you expect?  Did you print out intermediate values?  Did they correspond with your manual calculations?

Comment: What is `f(x)`. Is it `f(x)=sqrt(x)` and you are solving for `f(x)=num` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `(guess ** 2.0 + epsl)` to `(guess ** 2 - num)` in your equation.  You want to adjust your estimate every step by an amount proportional to your error, ie. your `diff` variable.

Answer (score 6):

One important skill in programming is knowing which information where will be most useful. If you add some simple debugging information:

```
while abs(diff) > epsl and _cnt < count:
    guess = guess - (guess ** 2.0 + epsl) / (guess * 2.0)
    diff = guess ** 2.0 - num
    print guess, _cnt
    _cnt = _cnt +1
print guess, _cnt
```

You can see that your program goes wrong quickly:

```
$ ./sqrt.py 
0.49995 0
0.249874989999 1
0.124737394941 2
0.0619678553654 3
0.0301770577385 4
0.0134316410297 5
0.00299326718803 6
-0.0152075217183 7
-0.00431591416548 8
0.00942707405618 9
-0.000590335594744 10
....
```

It appears to halve the number every iteration until it goes negative, when the behavior gets very difficult to tell just at a glance. But you can obviously tell that the very first few iterations are wrong.

Something that looks quite fishy to me: `(guess ** 2.0 + epsl)`

You shouldn't actually use epsilon when evaluating Newton's method for square roots -- after all, you're trying to make sure your *error* is less than epsilon.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are looking for zeroes of the function f = x^2+eps1. If eps1 is positive, there will be no real zeroes. This means that your program will oscillate around 0 forever after a certain point, as you saw. If you set eps1 to a negative value, I expect you would find a root.

Newton's method isn't bullet-proof, and there are cases where it can diverge.

Answer (score 1):

You also can use `guess = 0.5 * (guess + num/guess)`